# Load ListView of bitmap efficiently and responsively

Tags: android, listview, android-glide

I have looked at Glide and understand that Glide doesn't take Bitmap (or a Future of Bitmap) parameter in load function.

My current approach is to fall back to manual way following the blog here. [Multithreading For Performance](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), just replacing the download function to create the bitmap in real time.

I wonder is there any image libraries could handle this task? Thanks.

UPDATE:
Or I can actually save the Bitmap in advanced then only pass the file name to Glide. it loads the image the normal way. In this situation, I need to house-keep the cache file.

Comment: Are you downloading the image and converting it to bitmap?

Comment: no, not downloading the image. I have to create the image.

Comment: If you're creating it from canvas or other methods, what you can do is create a temporary file and use its location uri in glide's load method.

Comment: That's what I can think of too. I'm wondering if there is any library that could save me from writing few more lines of code.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/GlideBitmapPool

Comment: Thanks. let me take a look. :D